# Questions about the Moduli Space of Vector Bundles of rank 2 with trivial determinant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $M_0$ be the moduli space of rank 2 semi-stable vector bundles over X with trivial determinant which is a singular projective variety of dimension $3g-3$. $M_0$ is constructed as the $GIT$ quotient of the $R(2,p)$ by $SL(p)$.

Let $M_0^{s}$ be the points of moduli space corresponding to the semi-stable points of $R(2,p)$. Then the singular locus of $M_0$ is the Kummer Variety $\mathbb{K}$ or the complement of $M_0^{s}$. The elements of $\mathbb{K}$ are of the form $L\oplus L^{-1}$, where L is a line bundle of degree 0. $\mathbb{K}_0$ be bundles of the form $L\oplus L^{-1}$ such that $L=L^{-1}$, i.e., $L^2$ is trivial.

**Question 1**- What is meant by a Kummer Variety? Why $\mathbb{K}_0$ is the Kummer Variety of dimension g?

$\mathbb{Z_2}$ acts on $Jac_0$ by involution i.e., $(0,L)\longmapsto L$ and $(1,L)\longmapsto L^{-1}$

$\mathbb{K}$ $\cong$ $Jac_0//\mathbb{Z_2}$. There are $2^{2g}$ number of fixed points $\mathbb{Z_2^{2g}}=\{[L\oplus L^{-1}:L\cong L^{-1}]\}$of the action.

**Question2**.- Is this isomorphism is isomorphism as varieties?

**Question3-** Why are there are $2^{2g}$ number of fixed points of the action.

Thus $M_0$ has a stratification

$M_0=M_0^{s}\coprod(\mathbb{K}-\mathbb{Z_2^{2g}})\coprod Z_2^{2g}$.

Over each point in the deepest strata $\mathbb{Z_2^{2g}}$ there is unique closed orbit in $R(2,p)^{ss}$. By deformation theory, the normal space of the orbit at a point h, which represents $L\oplus L^{-1}$ where $L\cong L^{-1}$ is,

$H^{1}(End_0(L\oplus L))\cong H^{1}(\mathcal(O))\oplus \mathcal{sl}(2)$

**Question4**- Why is the last statement true?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can refer some books.

Comment: A good place to start would be the book "Moduli Spaces and vector bundles" (LMS Lecture Notes 359), in particular the lectures by Ramanan.

Answer (score 2):

I can give a partial answer to this question.

If you're looking at rank two vector bundles of the form $L \oplus L^{-1}$ over a curve $X$ of genus $g$ where $L$ has degree zero, then this is going to be isomorphic to $Pic_0(X)/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$, where the map in one direction is the obvious map
$$
L \mapsto [L \oplus L^{-1}]
$$
The point is that you can't tell the difference between $L \oplus L^{-1}$ and $L^{-1} \oplus L$, since if $L$ is a line bundle of degree zero (i.e. an element of $Pic_0(X)$), then so is $L^{-1}$.

Anyhow, $Pic_0(X)$ is an abelian variety of dimension $g$, and its quotient is called the Kummer variety, which is also of dimension $g$. This can be seen in a number of different ways, including the fact that $Pic_0(X) \cong H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)/H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$. Since $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a $g$-dimensional vector space and the image of $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ has maximal rank, the quotient is topologically isomorphic to $S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1$ (where there are $2g$ factors).

The fixed points of the action of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ are clearly those line bundles $L$ such that the swapping of factors $L \oplus L^{-1} \leftrightarrow L^{-1}\oplus L$ makes no difference; these are exactly those lines bundles $L$ such that $L^2 = \mathcal{O}_X$ as suggested, which are precisely the 2-torsion points of $Pic_0(X)$; as this is $2g$ copies of $S^1$, there are $2^{2g}$ of these.

I see no reason why this would *not* be an isomorphism of varieties. The action of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $Pic_0(X)$ is reasonably well-behaved, so I see no reason why they aren't isomorphic...

Anyhow, one concrete example to think of is in the case $g = 2$. In such a case we get as the Kummer variety the quotient of an abelian surface $A$ by the action of $\pm1$, which has 16 fixed points which locally look like $\mathbb{C}^2/\pm1$. This is singular, and we can resolve each of these with a single blowup to obtain an exceptional $\mathbb{P}^1$; the resulting surface is a smooth K3 surface call the Kummer surface.

Comment: That said, I suppose this is not really a research-level question. Oh well.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. What about the normal space of the orbit?

Comment: Dear @Simon Rose, if you believe a question is not appropriate for the site, you may want to vote to close the question or flag it for closing (if you do not have enough reputation to vote to close).

Comment: Well, I started answering the question before I thought about it; after I answered I noticed other people had said so.